# Context path generated twice when using #{resource} value expression within facelet page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

I'm using the expression `#{resource['library:file']}` within a facelets page to generate an ajaxified button with an image within an RichFaces (4.2.2.Final) toolbar.

```
<h:form>
    <rich:toolbar height="40px">
        <rich:toolbarGroup>
            <a4j:commandButton value="my label" image="#{resource['icons:icon32.gif']}"/>
    </rich:toolbarGroup>
    </rich:toolbar>
</h:form>
```

generates the following code for the a4j:commandButton where the context path is generated twice.

```
<input type="image" alt="my label" 
    src="/com.test.my.context/com.test.my.context/faces/javax.faces.resource/icon32.gif?ln=icons" 
    value="my label" 
    onclick="RichFaces.ajax(&quot;j_idt73:j_idt76&quot;,event,{&quot;incId&quot;:&quot;1&quot;} );return false;" 
    name="j_idt73:j_idt76" id="j_idt73:j_idt76">
```

If I use `<h:graphicImage library="icons" name="icon32.gif"/>` within `rich:toolbarGroup` the generated URL is right.

Furthermore I've include the image by css using `background: url(#{resource['library:file']})` which doesn't gives the result I've searched for, but it works!

1. Is the expression `#{resource['library:file']}` only allowed within css files?
2. Where is the problem within my code?

Comment: This is not caused by `#{resource}` (try printing it in template text), but by `<a4j:commandButton>`. It's implicitly prepending the context path, apparently without checking if it's already been set by the developer. Consider reporting the issue to RichFaces.

Comment: The problem also affects RichFaces 4.3.0.M1 so I've created a new issue to JBoss community (JIRA). I will post the results here, if there is something new and noteworthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JIRA Issue RF-12523](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12523) it's fixed in 4.3.1.Final.